# Image processing output on CUDA and host are different

Tags: c, image-processing, cuda, gpgpu

I'm using Quadro NVS 290 for the image processing in CUDA-C. To verify the execution time on the GPU I'm doing the processing on host as well. The findings are that the execution time on GPU is more than the CPU, and the output images are both different. The algorithm which I've used here is the Gaussian Blur with three degree blurring for 512x512 lema image. Also this code doesn't work properly for other image dimension and grey-scale images.

The code is :

```
unsigned int width, height;

int mask[3][3] = { 1, 2, 1,
2, 4, 2,
1, 2, 1
};

int h_getPixel(unsigned char *arr, int col, int row, int k)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int denom = 0;

    for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
    {
        for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
        {
            if ((row + j) >= 0 && (row + j) < height && (col + i) >= 0 && (col + i) < width)
            {
                int color = arr[(row + j) * 3 * width + (col + i) * 3 + k];
                sum += color * mask[i + 1][j + 1];
                denom += mask[i + 1][j + 1];
            }           
        }
    }

    return sum / denom;
} // End getPixel

void h_blur(unsigned char *arr, unsigned char *result)
{
    for (unsigned int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        for (unsigned int col = 0; col < width; col++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
            {
                result[3 * row * width + 3 * col + k] = h_getPixel(arr, col, row, k);
            }
        }
    }
} // End h_blur

__global__ void d_blur(unsigned char *arr, unsigned char *result, int width, int height)
{
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    if (row < 0 || col < 0)
        return;

    int mask[3][3] = { 1, 2, 1,
        2, 4, 2,
        1, 2, 1
    };

    int sum = 0;
    int denom = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
    {
        for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
        {
            for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
            {
                if ((row + j) >= 0 && (row + j) < height && (col + i) >= 0 && (col + i) < width)
                {
                    int color = arr[(row + j) * 3 * width + (col + i) * 3 + k];
                    sum += color * mask[i + 1][j + 1];
                    denom += mask[i + 1][j + 1];
                }
            }
        }

        result[3 * row * width + 3 * col + k] = sum / denom;
    }
}

int  main(int argc, char **argv)
{
/************ Setup work ***********************/
unsigned char *d_resultPixels;
unsigned char *h_resultPixels;
unsigned char *h_devicePixels;

unsigned char *h_pixels = NULL;
unsigned char *d_pixels = NULL;

char *srcPath = .......;    // input image
char *h_resultPath = ......; // host output image
char *d_resultPath = ......; // device output image

FILE *fp_input;
FILE *fp_output;
FILE *fp_d_output;

unsigned char *inputFileData;
unsigned char *output_buffer;
unsigned char *d_output_buffer;

int nBlurDegree;

inputFileData = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * IMAGE_BUFFER_SIZE);
output_buffer = (unsigned char *)inputFileData;
d_output_buffer = (unsigned char *)inputFileData;

/* Read the uncompressed image file */
fp_input = fopen(srcPath, "r");

fread(inputFileData, IMAGE_BUFFER_SIZE, 1, fp_input);
fclose(fp_input);

unsigned int fileSize = (inputFileData[5] << 24) | (inputFileData[4] << 16) | (inputFileData[3] << 8) | inputFileData[2];
unsigned int dataOffset = (inputFileData[13] << 24) | (inputFileData[12] << 16) | (inputFileData[11] << 8) | inputFileData[10];
unsigned int imageSize = (inputFileData[37] << 24) | (inputFileData[36] << 16) | (inputFileData[35] << 8) | inputFileData[34];

width = (inputFileData[21] << 24) | (inputFileData[20] << 16) | (inputFileData[19] << 8) | inputFileData[18];
height = (inputFileData[25] << 24) | (inputFileData[24] << 16) | (inputFileData[23] << 8) | inputFileData[22];

h_pixels = (unsigned char *)malloc(imageSize);

h_resultPixels = (unsigned char *)malloc(imageSize);

inputFileData = inputFileData + dataOffset;
memcpy((void *)h_pixels, (void *)inputFileData, imageSize);

/************************** Start host processing ************************/

clock_t cpuStartTime, cpuEndTime;

cpuStartTime = clock();

// Apply gaussian blur
for (nBlurDegree = 0; nBlurDegree < BLUR_DEGREE; nBlurDegree++)
{
    memset((void *)h_resultPixels, 0, imageSize);

    h_blur(h_pixels, h_resultPixels);

    memcpy((void *)h_pixels, (void *)h_resultPixels, imageSize);        
}   

cpuEndTime = clock();

double cpuElapsedTime = (cpuEndTime - cpuStartTime) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

printf("\nCPU time elapsed:\t%.2f ms\n", cpuElapsedTime * 1000);

inputFileData = inputFileData - dataOffset;

memcpy(output_buffer, inputFileData, dataOffset);

output_buffer = output_buffer + dataOffset;

memcpy(output_buffer, h_resultPixels, imageSize);

output_buffer = output_buffer - dataOffset;

fp_output = fopen(h_resultPath, "w");

fwrite(output_buffer, fileSize, 1, fp_output);
fclose(fp_output);

/************************** End host processing **************************/

/************************** Start device processing **********************/

cudaError_t cudaStatus;

h_devicePixels = (unsigned char *)malloc(imageSize);

cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_pixels, imageSize);

cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_resultPixels, imageSize);

cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(d_pixels, h_pixels, imageSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

dim3 grid(16, 32);
dim3 block(32, 16);

// create CUDA event handles
cudaEvent_t gpuStartTime, gpuStopTime;
float gpuElapsedTime = 0;

cudaEventCreate(&gpuStartTime);
cudaEventCreate(&gpuStopTime);

cudaEventRecord(gpuStartTime, 0);   

for (nBlurDegree = 0; nBlurDegree < BLUR_DEGREE; nBlurDegree++)
{
    cudaStatus = cudaMemset(d_resultPixels, 0, imageSize);

    d_blur << < grid, block >> >(d_pixels, d_resultPixels, width, height);

    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(d_pixels, d_resultPixels, imageSize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);

    cudaStatus = cudaThreadSynchronize();
}

cudaEventRecord(gpuStopTime, 0);
cudaEventSynchronize(gpuStopTime);  // block until the event is actually recorded

cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(h_devicePixels, d_resultPixels, imageSize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

cudaEventElapsedTime(&gpuElapsedTime, gpuStartTime, gpuStopTime);

printf("\nGPU time elapsed:\t%.2f ms\n", gpuElapsedTime);

memcpy(d_output_buffer, inputFileData, dataOffset);

d_output_buffer = d_output_buffer + dataOffset;

memcpy(d_output_buffer, h_devicePixels, imageSize);

d_output_buffer = d_output_buffer - dataOffset;

fp_d_output = fopen(d_resultPath, "w");

fwrite(d_output_buffer, fileSize, 1, fp_d_output);
fclose(fp_d_output);

/************************** End device processing ************************/

// Release resources
cudaEventDestroy(gpuStartTime);
cudaEventDestroy(gpuStopTime);

cudaFree(d_pixels);
cudaFree(d_resultPixels);

cudaThreadExit();

free(h_devicePixels);
free(h_pixels);
free(h_resultPixels);

return 0;
} // End main
```

Comment: Did you have a concrete question to ask?

Comment: Are the kernel execution parameters correct or what is wrong at the GPU side? Also how to handle images of different dimensions and grey-scale images ?

Comment: Too broad, no clear question, no minimal code example. Please try to reedit your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with your code is that your data flow is broken.

1. `h_pixels` contains your initial data:

   ```
   memcpy((void *)h_pixels, (void *)inputFileData, imageSize);
   ```
2. You are over-writing your data at the end of the host blur routine, with the result data:

   ```
   memcpy((void *)h_pixels, (void *)h_resultPixels, imageSize);
   ```
3. You are then using this blurred data as the starting point for your device blur routine:

   ```
   cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(d_pixels, h_pixels, imageSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
   ```

At no point between steps 2 and 3 in your code do you replace the data pointed to by `h_pixels` with the original starting data.  Therefore it's not reasonable to expect that the device blur and host blur will generate the same result.  They are not starting with the same data.

Another problem with your code is that there is a subtle difference between your host and device code for the blur operation.  Specifically, in the host case (`h_blur`), each time `h_getPixel` is called, the variables `sum` and `denom` are initialized to zero (on each iteration of the `k` loop in `h_blur`).

However in your device code, you have a loop that is iterating over 3 color components, but `sum` and `denom` are not being reset to zero on each iteration of the `k` loop.

The following fully worked example has these problems fixed, and produces identical results between host and device for random sample data:

```
$ cat t626.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define IMW 407
#define IMH 887
#define IMAGE_BUFFER_SIZE (IMW*IMH*3)
#define BLOCKX 16
#define BLOCKY BLOCKX
#define BLUR_DEGREE 3

unsigned int width, height;

int hmask[3][3] = { 1, 2, 1,
2, 4, 2,
1, 2, 1
};


#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#define USECPSEC 1000000ULL

unsigned long long dtime_usec(unsigned long long prev){
  timeval tv1;
  gettimeofday(&tv1,0);
  return ((tv1.tv_sec * USECPSEC)+tv1.tv_usec) - prev;
}

int validate(unsigned char *d1, unsigned char *d2, int dsize){

  for (int i = 0; i < dsize; i++)
    if (d1[i] != d2[i]) {printf("validation mismatch at index %d, was %d, should be %d\n", i, d1[i], d2[i]); return 0;}
  return 1;
}

int h_getPixel(unsigned char *arr, int col, int row, int k)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int denom = 0;

    for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
    {
        for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
        {
            if ((row + j) >= 0 && (row + j) < height && (col + i) >= 0 && (col + i) < width)
            {
                int color = arr[(row + j) * 3 * width + (col + i) * 3 + k];
                sum += color * hmask[i + 1][j + 1];
                denom += hmask[i + 1][j + 1];
            }
        }
    }

    return sum / denom;
} // End getPixel

void h_blur(unsigned char *arr, unsigned char *result)
{
    for (unsigned int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        for (unsigned int col = 0; col < width; col++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
            {
                result[3 * row * width + 3 * col + k] = h_getPixel(arr, col, row, k);
            }
        }
    }
} // End h_blur

__global__ void d_blur(const unsigned char * __restrict__ arr, unsigned char *result, const int width, const int height)
{
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    int mask[3][3] = { 1, 2, 1,
        2, 4, 2,
        1, 2, 1
    };
    if ((row < height) && (col < width)){
      int sum = 0;
      int denom = 0;

      for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
      {
        for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
        {
            for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
            {
                if ((row + j) >= 0 && (row + j) < height && (col + i) >= 0 && (col + i) < width)
                {
                    int color = arr[(row + j) * 3 * width + (col + i) * 3 + k];
                    sum += color * mask[i + 1][j + 1];
                    denom += mask[i + 1][j + 1];
                }
            }
        }

        result[3 * row * width + 3 * col + k] = sum / denom;
        sum = 0;
        denom = 0;
      }
    }
}

int  main(int argc, char **argv)
{
/************ Setup work ***********************/
  unsigned char *d_resultPixels;
  unsigned char *h_resultPixels;
  unsigned char *h_devicePixels;

  unsigned char *h_pixels = NULL;
  unsigned char *d_pixels = NULL;

  int nBlurDegree;
  int imageSize = sizeof(unsigned char) * IMAGE_BUFFER_SIZE;

  h_pixels = (unsigned char *)malloc(imageSize);


  width  = IMW;
  height = IMH;


  h_resultPixels = (unsigned char *)malloc(imageSize);
  h_devicePixels = (unsigned char *)malloc(imageSize);

  for (int i = 0; i < imageSize; i++) h_pixels[i] = rand()%30;
  memcpy(h_devicePixels, h_pixels, imageSize);

/************************** Start host processing ************************/
  unsigned long long cputime = dtime_usec(0);
// Apply gaussian blur
  for (nBlurDegree = 0; nBlurDegree < BLUR_DEGREE; nBlurDegree++)
  {
    memset((void *)h_resultPixels, 0, imageSize);

    h_blur(h_pixels, h_resultPixels);

    memcpy((void *)h_pixels, (void *)h_resultPixels, imageSize);
  }
  cputime = dtime_usec(cputime);


/************************** End host processing **************************/

/************************** Start device processing **********************/


  cudaMalloc((void **)&d_pixels, imageSize);

  cudaMalloc((void **)&d_resultPixels, imageSize);

  cudaMemcpy(d_pixels, h_devicePixels, imageSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  dim3 block(BLOCKX, BLOCKY);
  dim3 grid(IMW/block.x+1, IMH/block.y+1);

  unsigned long long gputime = dtime_usec(0);

  for (nBlurDegree = 0; nBlurDegree < BLUR_DEGREE; nBlurDegree++)
  {
    cudaMemset(d_resultPixels, 0, imageSize);

    d_blur << < grid, block >> >(d_pixels, d_resultPixels, width, height);

    cudaMemcpy(d_pixels, d_resultPixels, imageSize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);
  }
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  gputime = dtime_usec(gputime);
  cudaMemcpy(h_devicePixels, d_resultPixels, imageSize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  printf("GPU time: %fs, CPU time: %fs\n", gputime/(float)USECPSEC, cputime/(float)USECPSEC);

  validate(h_pixels, h_devicePixels, imageSize);
/************************** End device processing ************************/

// Release resources
  cudaFree(d_pixels);
  cudaFree(d_resultPixels);

  free(h_devicePixels);
  free(h_pixels);
  free(h_resultPixels);

  return 0;
} // End main
$ nvcc -O3 -o t626 t626.cu
$ ./t626
GPU time: 0.001739s, CPU time: 0.057698s
$
```

The above timing results (GPU about 30x faster than CPU) were produced with a Quadro5000 GPU on CentOS 5.5 and CUDA 7 RC.  Your Quadro NVS 290 is a lower-powered GPU and so it will not do as well.  When I run this code on a Quadro NVS 310, I get a result indicating the GPU is only faster than the CPU by about 2.5x

Comment: Thanks for finding the bugs. The code is working fine on Quadro NVS 290 with execution time more on GPU front. But this code is not able to handle different images of other dimensions.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, and it's due to your fixed dimensions throughout including fixed grid and block dimensions.  You'll need to learn more about CUDA programming if you want to address that.

Comment: I'm new to CUDA programming. How can I efficiently handle the kernel configuration parameters, by not using any magic numbers.

Comment: I've modified the code to handle more-or-less arbitrary image sizes.  The key changes are to choose appropriate grid and block dimensions, and condition the kernel code so that launched threads outside of the valid range do nothing.

Comment: Is it like you are changing the width and height each time keeping grid and block dimensions fixed? Also in the modified code what is the purpose of this line:                                                                                                                   for (int i = 0; i < imageSize; i++) h_pixels[i] = rand()%30;

Comment: Can you explain this structure...dim3 grid(IMW/block.x+1, IMH/block.y+1);

Comment: The for-loop fills my image with random data.  the dim3 variable is used to set the size of the grid, which is the number of blocks in the X dimension and the number of blocks in the Y dimension.  You had a similar dim3 grid definition in your code, it was just set to fixed values.

Comment: I don't think adding 1 in both X and Y dimension of grid is valid. In my code I'm directly reading the width & height from the input image rather than defining them as macros. So this works fine for 512x512 image:    dim3 grid(width / block.x, height / block.y); But the same doesn't work properly for 320x240 bitmap image. What could be the plausible reason?